# Django - Postgress - atomicly create instance only if doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unique-constraint

I want to create an element, but only if a 'similar' object doesn't exist. For example:

```
name_to_be_created = "John"
age_to_be_created = 15
if not Person.objects.filter(name=name_to_be_created, age__gte=age_to_be_created).exists():
    Person.objects.create(name=name_to_be_created, age=age_to_be_created)
```

Note that intentionally the condition is not simple enough to allow using `get_or_create`

As I understand it using a transaction when using `select` and then `insert` doesn't guarantee this kind of consistency

I'm using Postgres

Comment: Hi, what is the question?

Comment: The only condition is that the `age_to_be_created` must be greater than the latest exiting row for that `Person`?

Comment: If you are worried about race conditions with multiple apps, use select_for_update to use locking in the DB https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update